# How to detect if, one sprite node is the same colour as another sprite node then add to score if they are the same if not "restart game"

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

So I have a "Ball" (player) that you control, when the player hits a "colorOrb" the Ball changes to that colour all at random, so that part works, but I'm stuck on how to detect if the player changes to a random colour on how to detect if once it goes through a wall also of a random colour if they are both the same colour and add +1 or whatever to score.
I've tried multiple ways but can't seem to figure it out. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `Ball` and a `Wall` class

```
class Ball: SKSpriteNode { }
class Wall: SKSpriteNode { }
```

In your `didBegin(contact:)` just compare the `color` property.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node
        let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node

        guard let nodes: (ball:Ball, wall:Wall) = (nodeA, nodeB) as? (Ball, Wall) ?? (nodeB, nodeA) as? (Ball, Wall) else { return }

        if nodes.ball.color == nodes.wall.color {
            // same color
            // TODO...
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: so i added that and it says " casts from (SKphysicsBody, SKPhysicsBody) to unrelated type (Ball,Wall) always fail,i think i know why but probably not, how i made the player touch the orb colour changers i compared the physics bodies of both so if player touches red orb change player to SKcolor.redcolor so would that have any affect on the out come of the code you gave? thats the only thing i can think of

Comment: @Pulse: Sorry my mistake, I updated my code. Please try again.

Comment: nice job with the coalesce, looks better than the ternary,  give the tuple some labels to make it readable, then you no longer need let ball and let wall,  2 less variables means less code, less time used

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: thanks. I updated the code with your suggestions.

Comment: no worries, your taking the time to help me out haha thanks, still one question, I'm new to this Xcode and swift, but where do i declare class Ball and class Wall, up in the same location as my other variable just under class Game Scene? and "let Ball" and "let Wall" are saying "definition conflicts with previous value" and if ball says "instance type colour cannot be used on type ball"

Comment: @Pulse: These are pretty basic questions. You should first read the [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/).

Comment: yea sorry i have a bad habit of diving into things not fully prepared and just trying to play around with it and figure it out, ill read that and this swift 2.0 book i have probably better to just read the updated site u posted, thanks for the help I'm sure when i get it all coded right your code will work perfectly, cause i do get what you did in it now :) I'm also new to this site someone got mad at me last question for something, so whats the appropriate way to "mark" this question?

Comment: @Pulse you won't find the answer to "where to declare..." something in The Swift Programming Language book. Unfortunately. You'll have to divine that yourself. These books don't teach program design, more's the pity. And there's a myriad of choices. None of which Apple teaches, either. You could make your own new files for these, or above the functions in the "viewController". Only really these two places. How you call them to create them changes based on where they are. Someone smarter than me could summarise this in no-time at all.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Swift doesn't support runtime type casting with tuples – it only relies on the static types (see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/2ab42f3e92447bda0e7e572c7e3f9d04) for an example). Therefore in this case, because `nodeA` and `nodeB` are typed as `SKNode?`, the `guard` will always fail.